# Hibernate slows down over time

Tags: java, hibernate

My project makes extensive use of Hibernate to retrieve data objects from Postgresql (we are using Hibernate 4.2.15 and Postgresql 10.1-3). The code looks like this:

```
public void hibernateSlowdown() {
    BigObject bigObject = new BigObject();
    for (int i=0 ; i<nObjects ; i++) {
        Target target = targetCrud.retrieve(i); // targetCrud has the Hibernate calls
        BigObject.target = target; 
        ...
        CustomSerializer.serialize(bigObject);
    }
}
```

Logging shows that as the code runs over a very large number of iterations (roughly 10,000), each iteration takes longer than the last one. I'm convinced that the issue is related to Hibernate caching for the following reasons:

1. Through extensive logging it's clear that the only part of the loop that takes longer on every iteration is the targetCrud.retrieve(i) call.
2. When I added a brute-force call to the session clear() method, the performance dramatically improves and in particular no longer gets slower over time (or rather it gets slower until the clear() call, and then speeds up again).

I had hopes that using the evict() method to remove the Target objects from the Hibernate cache would give me comparable results, but -- no dice, with an aggressive effort to evict all the Target objects, execution still slows down over time in the same way as described above.

One issue is that the Target class is a kind of a mess of embedded objects within embedded objects, some objects have FetchType or Cascade annotations while others do not, in particular the Target has an embedded Aperture object which in turn has the parent Target object as a member (so target.aperture.target = target).

Any suggestions for how I can address the performance without the brute force of clearing the cache? Or how I can make the evict() calls work out comparably to the cache clears? What do I need to know about fetch types, cascades, etc., to make sure that an object with multiple layers of embedded objects really gets removed from the cache? Or is there something more fundamental about the way the Hibernate cache works that means that eviction will not solve my problem and I will have to live with cache clearing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you call `close` ?

Comment: I don't. Sessions and transactions are handled at a higher level in the code; so it's eventually called, but not until after all retrieval is completed.